# How to point a domain to a VPS when the host of the VPS has an static IP address

Tags: dns, ip, vps

I have a physical server which already has a static IP address (12.34.56.78) and I can easily point a domain to it using an A record.
Now I have  built a VPS on that server which can be accessed by a local IP (192.168.1.22) via the main server or any other computer in its range.
I want to point another domain to this VPS, but since the VPS doesn't have a valid IP, I can not do it the same way. i.e. I can not use A record.
Is there anyway I can point the domain to my VPS?

Comment: You're going to have to use network address translation (NAT) or port forwarding or something like that. Your VPS server has to know which packets to route to the VPS itself. I don't think this is trivial, but it's not necessarily hard either. What VM platform are you using for the VPS? Virtualbox? vmware?

Comment: If you don't want to use NAT; check if can get multiple IP adresses from your network provider